# How to programmatically get the package name for the launcher and task switcher?

Tags: android, android-launcher

Is there any way to programatically get the package name of the home launcher and task switcher, i.e. the apps that get launched when I press the home button and task switcher button respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home Screen package launcher

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
ResolveInfo defaultLauncher =getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
String defaultLauncherStr = defaultLauncher.activityInfo.packageName;
```

Comment: Thanks. How about the Android task switcher/recent apps package name?

Comment: I've tested on 2 phones and they are both "com.android.systemui". Is this consistent among all Android devices?

Comment: No they are not always the same! Did you find a method to find the package name for the task switcher?